# Unable to have display: inline-block and width:100% at the same time

Tags: html, css, styles, width, inline

I am not a CSS professional. So I only know some basics of it. My task is to have 100% body width and at the same time it should not wrap the contents when browser window resizes.

To achieve this I added `display: inline-block` to my body tag's CSS style. But when I does that the width gets decreased. Then I try to add `width:100%` to body style. The width changed as I wanted but then `display: inline-block` stopped working. How to enable both these properties at the same time?

```
<body style="display: inline-block; width:100%"><!--content---></body>
```

Comment: The code I can post is given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to fix the `body` width? simply use a container inside the body if you want like

CSS

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

OR if you want your content area to be `100%` than just change your CSS to this

CSS

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked. And one more thing I want to ask is that when I applied this style to home page, it worked like a charm. But when applied to other pages linked to it, it has the same problem as in the question. What can be the reason? The structure of all other pages are same as that of Home page.

Comment: @ShivaPareek It depends on your other styles, the position of elements, whether they are `absolute`, `relative` etc